# How do ES6 async/await work with Observables and streams when they fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, es6-promise

So, I've been trying to replicate this code:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/np/blob/370ef638344ab7115c956b75dc2823850084da39/index.js#L16

And it works. However, if the promise fails, I get an "unhandled promise" warning. Where does the catch statement belong on something like this if at all? Is there a better way to source information like this?

```
(node:48454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: np patch --no-cleanup


    at makeError (/Users/daghassi/git/build/node_modules/execa/index.js:172:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/Users/daghassi/git/build/node_modules/execa/index.js:277:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:48454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
(node:48454) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:48454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: np patch --no-cleanup


    at makeError (/Users/daghassi/git/build/node_modules/execa/index.js:172:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/Users/daghassi/git/build/node_modules/execa/index.js:277:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:48454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
(node:48454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: np patch --no-cleanup
```

Comment: can you add a stack trace please

Comment: @NaorTedgi updated original with an example of the stack trace I see when the command I call via this method throws an error on exit.

Comment: use async keyword to the function definition

Answer (score 0):

Just put a try/catch block around your await call. This should be the same as if you would call a Promise and provide a catch function.

So if you have a function which `getPromise()` which returns a promise, you simply do this.

```
async function asyncFunction() {
    try {
        const result = await getPromise();
    } catch (error) {
        // Add your error handling code here
    }
}
```